# Copy part of some SQL Server rows into same database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server database where I want to copy parts of the rows, and the other part of the row needs to be filled with new data, and into the same table. For example:

Table name: budget

```
ItemID   Item   Date
1         A     4/22/2012
2         B     4/15/2012
3         C     4/24/2012
```

When I copy the table, I want to copy the `item` column, but not the `date` column into the same table. The `date` column will get today's date, but Item will copy rows. Like below.

table name: budget

```
ItemID   Item   Date
1         A     4/22/2012
2         B     4/15/2012
3         C     4/24/2012
4         A     5/6/2012
5         B     5/6/2012
6         C     5/6/2012
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT Item 
INTO Budget 
FROM Budget
```

But I get error

> There is already an object named 'Budget' in the database.

Also, I'm not sure how after I copy the rows to fill the rest of the column with new `date` data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try insert instead.  Generate a query that has the new rows, and try something like:

```
Insert into <table>
    Select *
    From <q>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a new table called "Budget" which already exists by "SELECT INTO" statement.

Is your ItemID auto increment? Try this.

```
SELECT * into Budget FROM Budget_Temp

INSERT INTO Budget(Item,Date)
SELECT Item,'5/6/2012' FROM Budget_Temp

DROP TABLE Budget_Temp
```

Comment: Your answer was useful, it was actually a combination of both answers that helped me but this is my first time posting and dont know how to accept multiple answers. so, thank you.